# MongoHQ connection error on cloudbees in running application

Tags: cloudbees, mongohq

My application was running perfectly on cloudbees . Suddenly I got MongoHQ connection error .
When I restarted my application without making any change in the application , It was running perfectly again .

Caused by: java.io.IOException: couldn't connect to [sawyer.mongohq.com/***] bc:java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host
    at com.mongodb.DBPort._open(DBPort.java:228)
    at com.mongodb.DBPort.go(DBPort.java:112)
    at com.mongodb.DBPort.go(DBPort.java:93)

Is there any reason why cloudbees mongohq stop connecting in running application .

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like there was an issue with Mongo connectivity - most likely at the Mongo end since I believe they live on AWS the same as the CloudBees app servers.

- Check if you use the sawyer mongo instance
- Check if problems started around this outage - http://status.mongohq.com/services/sawyer/2013/1/8

Comment: Thanks Ben for your reply . We are using sawyer mongo instance .

Comment: If you have any concerns, I would suggest reaching out to MongoHQ's support team. They are very helpful and can offer tips and suggestions.